# Single machine code instance generated for all instances of a template in C++: Is it feasible and/or possible?

Tags: c++, templates, theory, compiler-optimization

I have been thinking about this, and I think I read about it *somewhere*, but I can no longer find more information about this.

Just for theoretical, not pratical purposes, is it possible, feasible, and/or practical to generate **a single** template instance, that is able to handle all instances of such a template? Has any compiler been able to do this?

For instance, consider this class template...

```
template<typename T>
class UselessCalculator {
    private:
        T   result;

    public:
        UselessCalculator() : result(0) {}

        UselessCalculator &operator=(T what) {
            this->result = what;
            return *this;
        }

        UselessCalculator &operator+=(T what) {
            this->result += what;
            return *this;
        }

        UselessCalculator &operator-=(T what) {
            this->result -= what;
            return *this;
        }

        UselessCalculator &operator*=(T what) {
            this->result *= what;
            return *this;
        }

        UselessCalculator &operator/=(T what) {
            this->result /= what;
            return *this;
        }
};
```

For any `T`, `UselessCalculator` has sort of a list of requireements for it to be used as a template argument for it, much like concepts. In this case, the requirements are:

- Being initializable by means of `T(0)`.
- Have overloaded `operator+=(T, T)`.
- Have overloaded `operator-=(T, T)`.
- Have overloaded `operator*=(T, T)`.
- Have overloaded `operator/=(T, T)`.

Now, according to this stupid "single instance fits all" idea, how would this be **implemented**? I thought that the following C code may illustrate a posibility...

```
struct UselessCalculatorTemplateVirtualTable {
    struct  someFunkyImplementationOfStdTypeInfo *type;
    void    (*constructInt)(void*, int);
    void    (*copyConstruct)(void*, const void*);
    void    (*moveConstruct)(void*, void*);
    void    (*destruct)(void*);
    void    (*operatorAddAssign)(void*, const void*);
    void    (*operatorSubtractAssign)(void*, const void*);
    void    (*operatorMultiplyAssign)(void*, const void*);
    void    (*operatorDivideAssign)(void*, const void*);
};

// I won't repeat that long name all over the place...
typedef struct UselessCalculatorTemplateVirtualTable VirtualTable;

void UselessCalculatorConstruct(VirtualTable *table, void *this) {
    table->constructInt(this, 0);
}

void UselessCalculatorCopy(VirtualTable *table, void *this, const void *what) {
    table->copyConstruct(this, what);
}

void UselessCalculatorMove(VirtualTable *table, void *this, void *what) {
    table->moveConstruct(this, what);
}

void UselessCalculatorDestruct(VirtualTable *table, void *this) {
    table->destruct(this);
}

void UselessCalculatorAddAssign(VirtualTable *table, void *this, void *what) {
    table->operatorAddAssign(this, what);
}

void UselessCalculatorAddAssign(VirtualTable *table, void *this, void *what) {
    table->operatorSubtractAssign(this, what);
}

void UselessCalculatorMultiplyAssign(VirtualTable *table, void *this, void *what) {
    table->operatorMultiplyAssign(this, what);
}

void UselessCalculatorDivideAssign(VirtualTable *table, void *this, void *what) {

    table->operatorDivideAssign(this, what);
}
```

Now, the sole thing the compiler has to "instantiate" for each `UselessCalculator<T>` is the `VirtualTable` and helper functions (if any). For example, `UselessCalculator<int>` would translate to...

```
#define real(what) ((int*)what)

void constructInt(void *this, int what) {
    *real(this) = what;
}

void copyConstruct(void *this, const void *what) {
    *real(this) = *real(what);
}

void moveConstruct(void *this, void *what) {
    *real(this) = *real(what);
}

void destruct(void *this) {}

void operatorAddAssign(void *this, const void *what) {
    *real(this) += *real(what);
}


void operatorSubtractAssign(void *this, const void *what) {
    *real(this) -= *real(what);
}


void operatorMultiplyAssign(void *this, const void *what) {
    *real(this) *= *real(what);
}


void operatorDivideAssign(void *this, const void *what) {
    *real(this) /= *real(what);
}
```

Then, taking this into account...

```
int main() {
    UselessCalculator<int> myUselessCalc;
    myUselessCalc += 10;
    myUselessCalc *= 10;
    myUselessCalc -= 10;
    myUselessCalc /= 10;
}

VirtualTable virtualTableInt = {
    &someFunkyImplementationOfStdTypeInfoForInt,
    constructInt,
    copyConstruct,
    moveConstruct,
    destroy,
    addAssign,
    subtractAssign,
    multiplyAssign,
    divideAssign
    };
```

Could translate into this C code... (not taking exceptions into account!)

```
struct UselessCalculatorInt {
    int result;
};

int main() {
    int tmpStorage;

    UselessCalculatorInt myUselessCalc;
    UselessCalculatorConstruct(&virtualTableInt, &myUselessCalc);

    tmpStorage = 10;
    UselessCalculatorAddAssign(&virtualTableInt, &myUselessCalc, &tmpStorage);

    tmpStorage = 10;
    UselessCalculatorSubtractAssign(&virtualTableInt, &myUselessCalc, &tmpStorage);

    tmpStorage = 10;
    UselessCalculatorMultiplyAssign(&virtualTableInt, &myUselessCalc, &tmpStorage);

    tmpStorage = 10;
    UselessCalculatorDivideAssign(&virtualTableInt, &myUselessCalc, &tmpStorage);

    UselessCalculatorDestroy(&virtualTableInt, &myUselessCalc);
    return 0;
}
```

I know this would beat all the purpose of templates, a lot of people won't like the idea (I don't like it, I'm just curious), and the code will probably be less efficient, both CPU- and memory-wise, not to mention it's almost unoptimizable and they wouldn't be "templates" anymore. But other ones have *ab*used them worse in the past, no? ;). **BTW**, better of to have a switch to disable this, if ever implemented, whenever necessary, because template metaprogramming would become near to useless.

So, my question is, if haven't been clear enough, is all this mess feasible, practical, implementable? Has some toolchain done this successfully? Would it provide any benefits that could outweight its obvious overheads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you are basically asking if some compiler can implement what is often called "compile-time polymorphism" (C++ templates) through run-time polymorphism ("classic" OOP with virtual functions).

While it is probably theoretically possible (at least to some limited degree), if really goes against the language  design principles. Templates were provided specifically as an efficient replacement for run-time polymorphism in contexts where compile-time polymorphism is more appropriate. The whole purpose of templates is to be different from "ordinary" run-time polymorphism. And a lot of template features depend critically on their compile-time nature.

The idea is that if you used templates, it means that you *want* compile-time polymorphism, not run-time polymorphism.

That's one side of the medal. The other side is that poorly written template code can lead to unnecessary code bloat, by forcing compile-time polymorphism (i.e. repetitive instantiation of the same code) in situations where run-time polymorphism would have easily achieved the same thing with much less code bloat and with negligible performance penalty. From that point of view, implicit automatic switch to run-time polymorphism in template code might be beneficial. But I believe the language in its current state is not tailored for that. This is something that you are expected to explicitly do yourself.

Comment: AFAIK, this is how Java implements its "generics" (i.e. templates): implicitly using runtime polymorphism.